# Tidy evaluation syntax in R user-defined function

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tidyeval, quosure

I want to define a generic function

```
func_boxplot2 <- function(tmp, xvar, yvar, groupvar)
{
  xvar <- enquo(xvar)
  yvar <- enquo(yvar)
  groupvar <- enquo(groupvar)

  # If variable yield exists, put concentrations to NA for all yields < annual_yield_thres
  if( "yield" %in% names(tmp) )
  {
    tmp <- tmp %>%
      mutate_at(vars(!!yvar), ~ifelse(round(yield, 0) < 85, NA, .))
  }
  
  # Compute IQR for each year
  tmp_iqr <- tmp %>%
    group_by(!!groupvar) %>%
    summarise(iqr=IQR(!!yvar, na.rm = TRUE))
  
  p <- ggplot(data = tmp %>% mutate_at(vars(!!yvar), ~ifelse(tmp_iqr[which(tmp_iqr[[!!groupvar]] %in% (!!xvar)),]$iqr == 0, . + runif(1, -0.01, 0.01), . )), aes(x = !!xvar, y = !!yvar))
  p <- p + stat_boxplot(aes(group = !!groupvar), na.rm = TRUE, coef = 10000)   # Trick (large unrealistic coef value) so whiskers end at min(y) & max(y)
  p <- p + geom_boxplot(na.rm = TRUE, outlier.shape = NA)

  return(p)
}
```

which is able to plot boxplot whiskers extending to min/max even when the IQR is 0. I am trying to achieve this by adding tiny random numbers (below significance level) to the incriminate data to avoid IQR=0.

However, I must have missed something in the syntax about quosure, because running this function

```
func_boxplot2(data, date, days, date)
```

with the dataset

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("2010", "2011", "2012", 
"2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), station = c("41B011", "41MEU1", "41N043", "41R001", 
"41R012", "41WOL1", "41B011", "41MEU1", "41N043", "41R001", "41R012", 
"41WOL1", "41B011", "41MEU1", "41N043", "41R001", "41R012", "41WOL1", 
"41B011", "41MEU1", "41N043", "41R001", "41R012", "41WOL1", "41B011", 
"41MEU1", "41N043", "41R001", "41R012", "41WOL1", "41B011", "41MEU1", 
"41N043", "41R001", "41R012", "41WOL1", "41B011", "41MEU1", "41N043", 
"41R001", "41R012", "41WOL1", "41B011", "41MEU1", "41N043", "41R001", 
"41R012", "41WOL1", "41B011", "41MEU1", "41N043", "41R001", "41R012", 
"41WOL1", "41B011", "41MEU1", "41N043", "41R001", "41R012", "41WOL1"
), days = c(16, 15, 45, 26, 14, 14, 32, 7, 87, 42, 24, 23, 25, 
25, 55, 29, 29, 16, 11, 14, 58, 21, 19, 10, 10, 14, 33, 18, 10, 
7, 9, 10, 19, 7, 8, 7, 1, 5, 15, 8, 1, 4, 5, 6, 14, 6, 5, 5, 
3, 5, 19, 8, 4, 5, 3, 4, 16, 3, 1, 3), yield = c(98.4817351598173, 
49.4520547945205, 95.8561643835616, 97.6712328767123, 98.2648401826484, 
95.1598173515982, 97.8767123287671, 27.9109589041096, 98.310502283105, 
98.972602739726, 97.203196347032, 96.2100456621005, 98.7818761384335, 
96.7554644808743, 97.4954462659381, 98.8046448087432, 98.747723132969, 
98.3037340619308, 99.0525114155251, 96.1986301369863, 97.1004566210046, 
96.4954337899543, 96.3698630136986, 98.2077625570776, 96.62100456621, 
98.3675799086758, 95.6963470319635, 96.8835616438356, 93.5844748858447, 
87.8196347031963, 91.2328767123288, 92.5570776255708, 81.5182648401827, 
82.7739726027397, 90.1826484018265, 87.1461187214612, 87.2153916211293, 
92.9986338797814, 94.6948998178506, 85.5760473588342, 92.3611111111111, 
96.2204007285975, 86.3698630136986, 86.4269406392694, 87.796803652968, 
93.2762557077626, 96.6438356164384, 95.6164383561644, 71.3812785388128, 
93.7442922374429, 96.3698630136986, 97.2602739726027, 95.7876712328767, 
94.7146118721461, 87.6141552511416, 43.0821917808219, 88.6872146118722, 
92.6826484018265, 90.365296803653, 86.541095890411), environ = structure(c(5L, 
4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 
3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("Urbain avec très forte influence du trafic", 
"Urbain avec forte influence du trafic", "Urbain avec influence modérée du trafic", 
"Urbain avec faible influence du trafic", "Urbain avec très faible influence du trafic", 
"Industriel avec influence modérée du trafic"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

gives me the following errors

```
 Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `days`.
x Must extract column with a single valid subscript.
x Subscript `date` has size 60 but must be size 1.
ℹ Input `days` is `(structure(function (..., .x = ..1, .y = ..2, . = ..1) ...`.
```

What is wrong in my syntax, please ?

Many thanks,

A.

======== UPDATE ==========

Using the suggested updated function

```
func_boxplot2 <- function(tmp, xvar, yvar, groupvar)
{
  # If variable yield exists, put concentrations to NA for all yields < annual_yield_thres
  if("yield" %in% names(tmp)) {
    tmp <-
      tmp %>%
      mutate(across({{yvar}}, ~ifelse(round(yield, 0) < 85, NA, .)))
  }
  
  tmp <-
    tmp %>%
    group_by({{groupvar}}) %>%
    mutate(
      across({{yvar}}, function (x) {
        ifelse(
          IQR({{yvar}}, na.rm = TRUE) == 0,
          x + runif(1, -0.01,0.01),
          x
        )
      })
    )

  ggplot(tmp, aes(x = {{xvar}}, y = {{yvar}})) +
    stat_boxplot(aes(group = {{groupvar}}), na.rm = TRUE, coef = 10000) +
    geom_boxplot(na.rm = TRUE, outlier.shape = NA)
}
```

results in the following plot

[image]

As stated in my comment, it seems that the processing of `tmp` output for all rows of the same year the first value `yvar` of this year which explains the plot. Indeed, commenting this block gives to following figure

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition in `ifelse` wasn't the correct length. You can change the `data` `ggplot` argument to this.

```
data =
  tmp %>%
    group_by(!!groupvar) %>%
    mutate_at(
        vars(!!yvar),
        if (IQR(., na.rm = TRUE) == 0) {
          . + runif(1, -0.01,0.01)
        } else {
          .
        }
    )
```

Your usage of `quosure` and `!!` is correct, however you should use the more recent [`{{` operator](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/02/glue-strings-and-tidy-eval/) instead.

This is the updated function

```
func_boxplot2 <- function(tmp, xvar, yvar, groupvar)
{
  # If variable yield exists, put concentrations to NA for all yields < annual_yield_thres
  if("yield" %in% names(tmp)) {
    tmp <-
      tmp %>%
      mutate(across({{yvar}}, ~ifelse(round(yield, 0) < 85, NA, .)))
  }
  
  tmp <-
    tmp %>%
    group_by({{groupvar}}) %>%
    mutate(
      across({{yvar}}, function (x) {
        if (IQR(x, na.rm = TRUE) == 0) {
          x + runif(length(x), -0.01, 0.01)
        } else {
          x
        }
      })
    )

  ggplot(tmp, aes(x = {{xvar}}, y = {{yvar}})) +
    stat_boxplot(aes(group = {{groupvar}}), na.rm = TRUE, coef = 10000) +
    geom_boxplot(na.rm = TRUE, outlier.shape = NA)
}
```

```
func_boxplot2(data, date, days, date)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks ! I recycled old code, but I will convert to the `{{` syntax. However, there is still something weird because boxplots are broken. The `group_by` and `ifelse` are replacing for each year all the values by the first one.

Comment: I have updated my question since the plot resulting from the function is still broken (see figures).

Comment: @Alessandro, see my updated answer. I've replaced `ifelse` with `if`/`else` as `IQR(x, na.rm = TRUE) == 0` only returns a single value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've received a good answer to your question.  Here's a completely different approach to the problem, answering a question you maybe should have asked:  instead of modifying the data, how to modify the stat used in producing the boxplot.

Normally the stat is `StatBoxplot`, and the important part of that `ggproto` object is the method `compute_group`.  When used in a plot, it returns a single row dataframe containing columns

```
[1] "ymin"        "lower"       "middle"      "upper"      
[5] "ymax"        "outliers"    "notchupper"  "notchlower" 
[9] "x"           "relvarwidth" "flipped_aes"
```

These mostly have a sort of obvious meaning; the only non-obvious one is `outliers`, which is a list-mode column, containing a single numeric vector holding the outliers.

So to get rid of outlier plotting completely, you could create an inherited stat which is just like `StatBoxplot`, but which modifies the result of `compute_group`:

```
NoOutlierStatBoxplot <- 
  ggproto("NoOutlierStatBoxplot", ggplot2::StatBoxplot,
          compute_group = function(..., self) {
            res <- ggproto_parent(StatBoxplot, self)$compute_group(...)
            res$ymin <- min(c(res$ymin, res$outliers[[1]]))
            res$ymax <- max(c(res$ymax, res$outliers[[1]]))
            res$outliers <- list(numeric())
            res
          })
```

(This is not really identical to what you were doing:  it still calculates the upper and lower quartiles after removing outliers.  If that matters to you, you might want a more extensive modification.)

With this modification, you can drop a lot of the code from `func_boxplot2`,
including dropping `stat_boxplot()`:

```
func_boxplot3 <- function(tmp, xvar, yvar, groupvar)
{
  # If variable yield exists, put concentrations to NA for all yields < annual_yield_thres
  if("yield" %in% names(tmp)) {
    tmp <-
      tmp %>%
      mutate(across({{yvar}}, ~ifelse(round(yield, 0) < 85, NA, .)))
  }
  
  ggplot(tmp, aes(x = {{xvar}}, y = {{yvar}})) +
    geom_boxplot(na.rm = TRUE, outlier.shape = NA, 
                 aes(group = {{groupvar}}), 
                 stat = NoOutlierStatBoxplot)
}

func_boxplot3(mydf, date, days, date)
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, this is the most elegant approach instead of modifying the data. However, your solution was beyond my current knowledge in R programming, but it will definitively enhance my perspective. Thanks.

Comment: The `ggplot2` vignette "Extending ggplot2" gives a fairly readable overview of this kind of thing.